# Prove that $x \leq \frac{a x+b y}{a +b} \leq y$ whenever $x \leq y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $$\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}, \forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}, \, x \leq y \Longleftrightarrow x \leq \frac{a x+b y}{a+b} \leq y \, \text{.}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
x = \frac{ax + bx}{a+b} \leq \frac{ax + by}{a + b} \leq \frac{ay + by}{a + b} = y
\end{align*}

Comment: Beautiful approach.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment

Answer (score 1):

Hint: simplify $\frac{ax+by}{a+b}-x,\,y-\frac{ax+by}{a+b}$, then use $a+b>0$.

Answer (score 0):

It may be interesting to note that $\frac{a}{a+b}$ and $\frac{b}{a+b}$ are both ratios between $0$ and $1$ , and their sum is $1$ . Using these ratios to mix $x$ and $y$ gives us a weighted average of $x$ and $y$ , which is somewhere between $x$ and $y$.